# Computing Final Grade Using For Loops and Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, average

I am currently in a Pre-AP Computer Science class. Our teacher has assigned us a project due by midnight tonight. The project requires that you make a program that asks what your name is, how many grades you are entering, asks for your grades, averages your grades, then returns a letter value (e.g. A, B, C), along with your name (e.g. "Iqbal, Noor"). I seemingly had all my code worked out and was only having an out of bounds error when I entered my grades in. However, my teacher said that the only way to fix this error was to make a giant for loop and put the entirety of my code in it. It doesn't make sense to me, so if that is the case, could someone please explain it?

If that is not the case, I would like to know what to do. I would not like someone to give me an answer, rather lead me in the process of thinking how I can move forward with this problem.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Tester {
public static void main (String[] args){
    //Prompt for first
    //Prompt for last
    //Prompt for # of assgmts to be averaged
    //for-loop = prompt to enter # grade until all grades are entered (use [])
    //loop through array again to calculate average
    //print info
    //prompt for multiple names and grades
    Scanner kbInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many students will you be entering?");
    int numOfStudents = kbInput.nextInt();
    String[] Students = new String[numOfStudents];

    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < Students.length; k++){
        System.out.println("Enter your first name.");
        String first = kbInput.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your last name.");
        String last = kbInput.next();
        Students[k] = last + ", " + first;
    }

    String finalGrade = "";
    System.out.println("How many grades will you be entering?");
    int numOfGrades = kbInput.nextInt();
    int[] Grades = new int[numOfGrades];
    int sum = 0;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < numOfGrades; j++){
        System.out.println("Enter your grades.");
        Grades[j] = kbInput.nextInt();
        sum+=Grades[j];
    }
    int average = sum/numOfGrades;
        if((average >= 90) && (average <= 100)){
            finalGrade = "A";
        }
        else if((average >= 80) && (average < 90)){
            finalGrade = "B";
        }
        else if((average >= 75) && (average < 80)){
            finalGrade = "C";
        }
        else if((average >= 70) && (average < 75)){
            finalGrade = "D";
        }
        else if(average < 70){
            finalGrade = "F";
        }
        String[] letterGrade = new String[numOfStudents];
        int count;
        for(count = 0; count < numOfStudents; count++){
            letterGrade[count] = finalGrade;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here are the directions for the project:

1. Create a new Java Project called FinalGrade with a single class called Tester.
2. Prompt the user to enter a student’s first name, followed by another prompt to enter the student’s last name.
3. Prompt the user to enter the number of assignments to be averaged (ex. 6).
4. Using a for-loop, prompt the user to enter the numeric grade (whole numbers only) until the exact number of assignments for the student are entered. NOTE: The grades should be stored in an array.
5. Loop back through the array of grades and calculate an average of the grades entered.
6. Print the following information (in the order shown) on the screen…
   a.  Student’s Last Name
   b.  Student’s First Name
   c.  Student’s Final Grade (Displayed as a Letter Grade and not the Numeric Value)
   Example Output…
   Howard, Derek – A

Going Beyond…
1.  Alter your application to allow entry of multiple students and grades.

Comment: what you are trying to enter for your grades?

Comment: You have no connection between your `Grades` and your `Students`. So every student will habe the same grade! What i think your teacher  means is to make one big outer for loop that will be executed `numberOfStudents` times. In this for loop ask the Name and the Grades of each *one* student. Then continue with the next student. Think about creating a class `Student` which holds the James and the grades of one student

Comment: Advice not related to your particular issue: split your code into methods. It is good practice, helps isolate issues, makes your code more readable, divides responsibility (*"divide & conquer"*), ... most importantly, it will make it easier to design and write your code.

Comment: Your question is not properly clear. As per your code you are asking the number of grades. Whether this number of grades/subjects for all students. Like if 5 number of students and 3 grades. You have to ask 15 grades. 3 each for student. Then individually calculate average grade for each student.

Comment: @NoorIqbal suppose you code does not work as you expect. I tried to run it and it's stuck in the middle.

Comment: I don't think what your teacher is saying has to do with the out of bounds error. I think they are saying the program is supposed to loop `numOfStudents` times, each time asking for a new name and set of grades. It would help if you included a more explicit specification for the assignment but based on your description that's what it sounds like the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

if you are evaluating your grade by use of points, make a method that adds the total possible points, then adds the points you've earned, then divides to find the decimal score. be sure to multiply that product by 100. After that, using `Math.round()`, round your grade.

Comment: as domdom commented above, i also suggest dividing your code into methods. It makes it much easier to deal with.